# Commit state blank on first click. Vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

Commit state blank on first click. Vuex.

I can not get the updated state to the first click on a variable.

I've tried with Getters and it still does not work.

The first click in white and the other clicks normally.

Where am I going wrong?

Thank you guys.

action

```
    function login({ commit }, data) {
axios.post(`/api/token`, {
    username: data.username,
    password: data.password
  })
    .then(response => {
      if (response.status !== 400 || response.status !== 401) {
        commit('setLoginError', 'Bem vindo!')
      }
      commit('setToken', response.data)
    })
    .catch(error => {
      if (error.response.status === 400) {
        commit('setLoginError', 'Campos inválidos!')
      } else if (error.response.status === 401) {
        commit('setLoginError', 'Credências inválidas!')
      }
    })
    }
```

---

mutation

```
function setLoginError (state, data) {
  state.loginError = data
}
```

---

```
computed: {
    ...mapState('auth', ['loginError'])
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions('auth', ['login']),
    onSubmit () {
      this.login({ 'username': this.username, 'password': this.password })
      console.log(this.loginError)
    }
  }
```

Comment: Your action is asynchronous, but you `console.log` synchronously immediately after dispatching the action. Put the logging in your `setLoginError` mutation and you should see it work.

Comment: Could you explain how Tommy?

Comment: provide a codesandbox or codepen showcasing your problem, then we can help better.